# Node on zeronet giving validator errors

Tags: zeronet

Such an error is reported like every 20-30 sec. The node is currently in the processing of fetching the chain data, and the progress seems quite slow.

```
Feb  6 16:03:59 - validator.chain(1): Pushed: 2019-02-06T07:03:58Z, Treated: 2019-02-06T07:03:58Z, Completed: 2019-02-06T07:03:59Z
Feb  6 16:03:59 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: Unexpected error (validator):
Feb  6 16:03:59 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: Error, dumping error stack:
Feb  6 16:03:59 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:   Fetch of operations BMKXRaTDB8WGtthbrTsHurjf4MHXWD9sPBdmxbWLbHtfEPs3KRi:1 timed out
Feb  6 16:03:59 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:   Fetch of operations BMKXRaTDB8WGtthbrTsHurjf4MHXWD9sPBdmxbWLbHtfEPs3KRi:0 timed out
Feb  6 16:03:59 - node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:
Feb  6 16:03:59 - validator.peer(627): Worker crashed:
Feb  6 16:03:59 - validator.peer(627): Fetch of operations BMKXRaTDB8WGtthbrTsHurjf4MHXWD9sPBdmxbWLbHtfEPs3KRi:0 timed out
Feb  6 16:03:59 - validator.peer(627): Fetch of operations BMKXRaTDB8WGtthbrTsHurjf4MHXWD9sPBdmxbWLbHtfEPs3KRi:1 timed out
Feb  6 16:03:59 - validator.peer(633): Worker started for NetXSzLHKwSum:idqweozRypgw
Feb  6 16:04:00 - validator.peer(634): Worker started for NetXSzLHKwSum:idsbnfwujzAb
Feb  6 16:04:01 - validator.peer(635): Worker started for NetXSzLHKwSum:idqyipm7TGEN
Feb  6 16:04:01 - validator.peer(636): Worker started for NetXSzLHKwSum:idt74dtn7LL8
Feb  6 16:04:05 - validator.block: Block BMKXRaTDB8WGtthbrTsHurjf4MHXWD9sPBdmxbWLbHtfEPs3KRi succesfully validated
Feb  6 16:04:05 - validator.block: Pushed: 2019-02-06T07:04:03Z, Treated: 2019-02-06T07:04:03Z, Completed: 2019-02-06T07:04:05Z
Feb  6 16:04:05 - prevalidator.NetXSzLHKwSum.ProtoALphaAL(1): switching to new head BMKXRaTDB8WGtthbrTsHurjf4MHXWD9sPBdmxbWLbHtfEPs3KRi
Feb  6 16:04:05 - prevalidator.NetXSzLHKwSum.ProtoALphaAL(1): Pushed: 2019-02-06T07:04:05Z, Treated: 2019-02-06T07:04:05Z, Completed: 2019-02-06T07:04:05Z
Feb  6 16:04:05 - validator.chain(1): Update current head to BMKXRaTDB8WGtthbrTsHurjf4MHXWD9sPBdmxbWLbHtfEPs3KRi (fitness 00::000000000004ef62), same branch
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably connected to very few nodes, some of them very slow. You get timeouts while synchronizing the chain. Since there are very few nodes participating on Zeronet, and probably running on second-class servers, it is probably normal.